# How to add attributes to links/scripts?

Tags: templating

How do I add additional attributes values while registering a CSS/JS file?

I want to add a `media` attribute to one of the CSS links

Example code:

```
{% do view.registerCssFile(siteUrl ~ 'css/print.css', [ ['media' => 'print'] ]) %}
```

The above code produces an `Unexpected token "operator"` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% do view.registerCssFile(siteUrl ~ 'css/print.css', {'media' : 'print'}) %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can explain the syntax?

Comment: It's in the twig docs, for example here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#setting-variables